# explode, match and get value

Tags: jquery

I have a string:

```
title=Hello world&dropdown=on&count=on&hierarchical=on
```

and I want to explode this string from `&`, Like;

```
title=Hello world
dropdown=on
count=on
hierarchical=on
```

I already know the this names title, dropdown, count,hierarchical (but this names are not fixed, it can be anything),

Now I want to match this names (name means words before equal to sign) to name I know, if match then get value (words after equal to sign), like:

**if (name == myname) then get value**

```
var myname = dropdown;
if (dropdown == myname)alert(dropdown.value)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question but you can use `split` like: `"title=Hello world&dropdown=on&count=on&hierarchical=on".split("&")`

Answer (score 3):

Split the string into an array, then put that array into an object, then you can compare nicely:

```
var string = "title=Hello world&dropdown=on&count=on&hierarchical=on";
var stringArr = string.split("&");
console.log(stringArr);

var newObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    var parts = stringArr[i].split("=");
    newObj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Now, `newObj.title` will equal `Hello World`. Hope this helps.

Oh, and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KXMLp/

Answer (score 0):

split on & to create an array of strings, then split on = to get your name value pair. name is  first element[0], value is second element[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dropdown.contains(myname))
    alert(dropdown.value.substring(myname.length +1)
```